# Import GEXF graphs into Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

Is there any smart way to import gephi graphs (*.gexf) into mathematica ?
I mean other than converting to *.gml.

Comment: All supported graph formats are listed in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalDataFormats.html).

Comment: Out of all complex graph formats, Mathematica supports GML the best.  I recommend simply converting to GML.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Not Natively.

```
gephiexports = {"CSV", "GDF", "GEXF", "GraphML", "Pajek", "XLS","PDF", "SVG"};
Intersection[gephiexports, $ExportFormats]

(*   {"CSV", "GraphML", "Pajek","PDF", "SVG", "XLS"}   *)
```

GEXF is an XML based format so you may be able to crib a parser in Mathematica if you really want to.

**Update**
Gephi's website is somewhat contradictory on which is the best format other than GEXF.  On the one hand it says GraphML is the next best, on the other it says XLS has the most features.   [Source here](http://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/).  Given that both these are supported by Mathematica then it appears that apart from Gephi dynamics most things are supported.